# Restrict s3 file download to authenticated user in cognito (preferred) or anyone at all. They should only be able to view but not download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I wanted to know if there is any way to let the aws cognito users or anyone else be able to only view or play aws s3 files, but no matter how they try, they shouldn't be able to download any file in my bucket. The docs are really confusing me with the aws cloudformation stack launch (using lambda@edge, cloudfront, and cognito) and all.

Put in simple words, no matter who it is, whether authenticated or not, should only be able to view my s3 content/files not be able to download.

I am indeed new to AWS, would like the support a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. Because viewing / playing a file is the **exact same thing** as downloading the file. To be able to play a file you need to download it (or parts of it) first.

Note that this is not related to AWS. When you view an image in your browser you download it first, when you stream a movie from Netflix / Disney+ / Prime you download it (in tiny batches).